# Angular Testing Circular Dependency Error on Service in Component

Tags: angular, testing

I recently started to get myself into Angular Unit Testing and started to provide mock tests on a project of mine. At the moment, I can't figure out why I get the following error on one of my component tests:

*Error: NG0200: Circular dependency in DI detected for KeycloakService*

```
error properties: Object({ code: '200' })
Error: NG0200: Circular dependency in DI detected for KeycloakService
    at throwCyclicDependencyError (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:1352:1)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:11154:1)
    at R3Injector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:10979:1)
    at NgModuleRef$1.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:25053:1)
    at Object.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:24767:1)
    at lookupTokenUsingModuleInjector (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:3296:1)
    at getOrCreateInjectable (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:3408:1)
    at ɵɵdirectiveInject (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:14428:1)
    at NodeInjectorFactory.DashboardComponent_Factory [as factory] (ng:///DashboardComponent/ɵfac.js:6:7)
    at getNodeInjectable (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:3503:1)
```

*NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[KeycloakService -> HttpClient -> HttpClient]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!*

```
error properties: Object({ ngTempTokenPath: null, ngTokenPath: [ 'KeycloakService', 'HttpClient', 'HttpClient' ] })
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[KeycloakService -> HttpClient -> HttpClient]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!
    at NullInjector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:10823:1)
    at R3Injector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:10990:1)
    at R3Injector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:10990:1)
    at injectInjectorOnly (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:4907:1)
    at ɵɵinject (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:4911:1)
    at Object.KeycloakService_Factory [as factory] (ng:///KeycloakService/ɵfac.js:5:43)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:11158:1)
    at R3Injector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:10979:1)
    at NgModuleRef$1.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:25053:1)
    at TestBedRender3.inject (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/testing.js:1686:1)
```

*DashboardComponent*

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { TimeModule } from 'src/app/time/time.module';
import { KeycloakService } from 'src/app/services/keycloak.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.scss']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  public tacticalTimestamp = '';

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private keycloak: KeycloakService) {}
```

*DashboardComponentSpec*

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';

import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { KeycloakService} from 'src/app/services/keycloak.service';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

class MockRouter {
}

class MockKeycloakService {
}

describe('DashboardComponent', () => {
  let component: DashboardComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<DashboardComponent>;
  let router: Router;
  let keycloak: KeycloakService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ DashboardComponent ],
      providers: [
        { provide: Router, useClass: MockRouter },
        { provide: KeycloakService, useclass: MockKeycloakService },
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();

    router = TestBed.inject(Router);
    keycloak = TestBed.inject(KeycloakService);
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DashboardComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

*KeycloakService*

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http'
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { IKeycloakToken, IKeycloakTokenConvert } from 'src/app/interfaces/keycloak-token';

import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';
import { UserDataService } from './user-data.service';
import { MedicalQualification } from './user-data.service';

export enum ELoginResult {
  Success,
  Fail
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class KeycloakService {

  private token: IKeycloakToken = {} as IKeycloakToken;

  username = '';
  private intervalId: any;
  private intervalDelta = 60000;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private userData: UserDataService) { }
```

*KeycloakServiceSpec*

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { KeycloakService } from './keycloak.service';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { UserDataService } from './user-data.service';

class MockHttpClient {
}

class MockUserDataService {
}

describe('KeycloakService', () => {
  let service: KeycloakService;
  let httpClient: HttpClient;
  let userData: UserDataService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        { provide: HttpClient, useClass: MockHttpClient },
        { provide: UserDataService, useClass: MockUserDataService }
      ]
    });

    service = TestBed.inject(KeycloakService);
    httpClient = TestBed.inject(HttpClient);
    userData = TestBed.inject(UserDataService);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

The error gets especially weird, because in some components the KeycloakService works just fine...

Hope to find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently this was a typo mistake...

In the *DashboardComponentSpec* file I had to replace `useclass` with `useClass` and now the test passes. So the mistake is on my side, but the error logs didn't give any hints and the IDE didn't show anything either.
I will leave this question, maybe anyone will stumble across the same problems.